# buttons becoming visible sequentially

Tags: android, xml, button

I am trying to perform sort of a stop light function on a button press but instead there are two of every color. The desired functionality would be red, red, yellow, yellow, green, and green. I have tried to set a delay in between each color but it doesn't happen sequentially it just adds up the delays and they all show up at once.

Here is the snippet of the activity that I have tried to do this:

```
Button previewButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.preview_visual_button);
        final Button redButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.red_button_1);
        final Button redButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.red_button_2);
        final Button yellowButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yellow_button_1);
        final Button yellowButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yellow_button_2);
        final Button greenButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.green_button_1);
        final Button greenButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.green_button_2);

        redButton1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        redButton2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        yellowButton1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        yellowButton2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        greenButton1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        greenButton2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if(previewButton != null) {
            previewButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int time = 100;
                    delay(time);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void delay(final int c){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(c);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Button redButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.red_button_1);
                Button redButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.red_button_2);
                Button yellowButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yellow_button_1);
                Button yellowButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yellow_button_2);
                Button greenButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.green_button_1);
                Button greenButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.green_button_2);

                redButton1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                redButton2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                yellowButton1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                yellowButton2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                greenButton1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                greenButton2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }, c);

    }
```

EDIT:

```
previewButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int time = 1000;
                    redButton1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    delay(time);
                    redButton2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    delay(time);
                    yellowButton1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    delay(time);
                    yellowButton2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    delay(time);
                    greenButton1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    delay(time);
                    greenButton2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }   
            });
    }

    public void delay(final int time) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(time);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Update UI with Thread sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965291/update-ui-with-thread-sleep/10965337#10965337)

This will help answer the question if anyone visits in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Because that's basically what the postDelayed method does. It runs the code in the runnable after the specified time. So it delays for 100ms then runs just turns all the buttons on at once. Also I'm not sure what you are trying to do by calling Thread.sleep() on your UI thread. I would suggest writing a new method that just runs a Thread.sleep() inside a separate thread and call it between each pair of button toggle commands. Kind of like this

```
public void pause(int time) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(time);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
 }
```

Then basically call this in between each pair of button toggle statements. This should do the trick.

Comment: Implementing this didn't work for me. Even moving the delay off of the main thread and deleting postDelayed produced the same result. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post the code your writing specifically in as your button click handler. I'm not sure why this wouldn't work. Another option would be to call postDelayed after every pair of button state change calls.

Comment: please see edit. It acts as if it isn't reading the delays at all.